# How to apply loop in datagridview rows based on cell values

Tags: vb.net

I had this problem with looping in datagridview where i have 3 columns.
Columns 1, 2 and 3.

The case is when "Column2" value is equal or greater than 75, "Column3" value is equal to "Column1". Else "Column3" is equal to 0.

And if "Column2" value is "IP" or "NFE", "Column3" value is equal to is equal to 0.

Below is the illustration:

```
  Column1   Column2    Column3
     3         78        3
     3         76        3
     3         65        0
     3         IP        0
     3        NFE        0
```

I have tried this code;

```
Private Sub DGVGRADES_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVGRADES.CellValueChanged
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVGRADES.Rows
        If row.Cells(4).Value >= 75 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value.ToString <= 3 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value < 75 Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = 0
        ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value = "IP" Then
            row.Cells(0).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But returns me this error.

> Conversion from string "IP" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I really badly needed a help on this for my school requirement. Thanks

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Test the value for the strings "IP"  and "NFE" first. Then convert the value to a number (checking for errors) and test the numeric values.

Comment: Can you show me some sample code for it? I tried declaring a string equal to a certain number but it gives me the same result

Comment: I guess your table is bounded to your datagridview? If yes then the data type of your column is determined by your datatable. if no then turn your column at index 4 to be a string   DGVGRADES.Columns(4).ValueType = GetType(String)

Comment: No. The data of datagridview is loaded from a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an easy fix for your homework. BUT you should understand the code and not just copy/paste the answer.

```
Private Sub DGVGRADES_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVGRADES.CellValueChanged
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVGRADES.Rows
        If Double.TryParse(row.Cells(4).Value, Nothing) = False Then
            If row.Cells(4).Value.ToString = "NFE" Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = 0
            ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value.ToString = "IP" Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = 0
            End If
        Else

            If row.Cells(4).Value >= 75 Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
            ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value.ToString <= 3 Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
            ElseIf row.Cells(4).Value < 75 Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine but, if i change the "IP" into 75 or higher value, the row.cells(0).value does not change which is suppose to be equal to row.cells(3).value

Comment: @user9153800 your grid must have more than 3 column. This example is based on a 3 column grid. Obviously it's up to you to make sure the code works with your app. This is just an example to show you how to overcome your issue. Vote up the answer too! ;)